# Text Injection In Display

Tags: php, sql-server, web-applications, web

Ok, so I'm given a list of parts like so:

```
PartID    CatID    PartName
0             1           Part 1
1             2           Part 2
2             1           Part 3
3             3           Part 4
4             2           Part 5
5             2           Part 6
```

I'm using PHP to pull.   How can I inject a blurb of text at each change in CatID, without having to run multiple loops?

So on page, I can display it like:

```
"BLURB OF TEXT"
Part 1
Part 3
"BLURB OF TEXT"
Part 2
Part 5
Part 6
"BLURB OF TEXT"
Part 4
```

Here's the code so far.  I thought about putting in an assignment to = $row["CatID"], and checking to see if the variable == CatID, but it was always ==...

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["PartName"]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please re-state your question? I have no idea what you want. (Btw, didn't downvote you.)

Comment: What's your SQL query? You need an `ORDER BY` there.

Comment: Could you also add your version of the code that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my logic backwards....   grr, figures I get it figured out right after I ask for help...

```
                if($cCat == $row["catID"]){
                    //echo 'nothing here';
                }else{
                    echo '<a name="' . $row["PartCategory"] . '"></a>';
                    echo $this->GetPartCategories();
                    $cCat = $row["catID"];
                }
```

is what works, , and above the while statement is a $cCat = '';

I was trying

```
                if(!$cCat == $row["catID"]){
                    echo '<a name="' . $row["PartCategory"] . '"></a>';
                    echo $this->GetPartCategories();
                    $cCat = $row["catID"];
                }
```

which for some reason did not work.

p.s.  Already have an order by in my query.   It orders by the catID, partSortOrder, then partName

Comment: Don't worry, happens to the best of us. Good thing you found it out for yourself. Thanks for the accept + upvote! By the way, if your if does not contain anything, you might change it to `!=` and put the `else` code in there. removes unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

Put the ID in a variable that is outside the loop. That way you can check the previous ID and the current one. If the current one is not the same as the last one, echo some text:

```
$LastID = 0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["PartName"];
    if($row["CatID"] > $LastID)
    {
        // ID changed!
        echo "Insert Text!";
    }
    $LastID = $row["CatID"];
}
```

This, ofcourse, is assuming that the data is sorted ascending on `CatID` as your result that you want is showing.